# curl command with return value space unable to assign to variable in shell

Tags: powershell, shell

i am trying to get the whole value which will return from curl command having space . So value is assign up to the space after space the value is not showing.

```
val= $(curl https://google.com)
```

output :

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta: command not found
```

ideally it shuld

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

301 Moved

## 301 Moved

The document has moved
[here](https://www.google.com/).

Comment: hi. val="$(curl https://google.com)"

Comment: @Bhaal22 its not working

Comment: can you provide more info? which shell are you running? bash / zsh ?

Comment: if you do only $val without echo it is giving - <HTML><HEAD><meta: command not found

Comment: what do you expect? $val is a string. its not a command.

Answer (score 0):

Using `"` (double quotes) does the trick.

`val="$(curl https://google.com)"`

```
john@ns3272591$ val="$(curl https://google.com)"

john@ns3272591$ echo $val
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> <TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY> <H1>301 Moved</H1> T </BODY></HTML> moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
```

Comment: try with $val it will give you <HTML><HEAD><meta: command not found –

Comment: of course. and this is normal. as I said, $val is a string (html). if you do: ```$val``` shell will try to execute it. and this string is not a valid shell command. not sure to understand what you try to achieve.